# When i click on the Kotlin Repl in IntelliJ Idea , the window never opens . Nothing happens . Please anyone tell me how to fix this

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea

[Kotlin Repl does not open ,nothing happens on clicking it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2jObQ.png)

Answer (score 4):

My solution/workaround. What happens is, and by the way the Intellij ide warns you about this, that you create the project and when naming it you use a space or similar unsupported character and the ide still seems to create the project just fine but actually it doesn't. Your project comes out misconfigured and you can't use Kotlin Repl. The simplest solution is to replace any spaces (or similar forbidden characters) with a hyphen "-" or an underscore "_" or simply use cammelCase. Best of luck to everybody and hope future learners of kotlin see this and spend less time troubleshooting such a simple issue.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a project open when you click it? [This post](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/208353525-Kotlin-REPL-won-t-run) states: "At this time the Kotlin REPL requires you to have a project open. You don't need to configure anything specific in the project; a Java project with the default settings will run just fine. 
If you want to try Kotlin without configuring anything, you can use the online IDE at http://try.kotlinlang.org/"